# Does Pandas Have an Alternative to This Syntax I'm Currently Using?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter my `df` down to only those rows who have a value in column `A` which appears less frequently than some threshold. I currently am using a trick with two `value_counts()`. To explain what I mean:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C']) 

'''
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   1   4   5
2   6   7   8
'''
```

I want to remove any row whose value in the `A` column appears `< 2` times in the column `A`. I currently do this:

```
df = df[df['A'].isin(df.A.value_counts()[df.A.value_counts() >= 2].index)]
```

Does Pandas have a method to do this which is cleaner than having to call `value_counts()` twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably easiest to filter by group size, where the groups are done on column A.

```
df.groupby('A').filter(lambda x: len(x) >=2)
```